# Is it possible to call different function of class based views through different actions in template

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am new to django and i ahve gone through all the docs of django. right now if we give some link in template and defined that link in `urls.py` i.e which view is going to handle that link. like this `url(r'^dashboard/gift/$', login_required(CouponPageView.as_view())),`

But i have this little doubt can i call different function of a view on clicking different links present in template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind a class-based view is not to serve multiple resources (the targets of the links in your template). The idea is that the class-based view implements methods for the various HTTP methods (i.e. get, post, put, delete, head).

So you can server an HTTP GET of a certain URI using the SomeView.get() method, or you can handle a POST to the same resource from the post() method in the same SomeView class. This is helpful to support object oriented code, as the different methods on the object will typically share some resources.

If you want to handle different URL's, write different View classes. If their functionality is similar, use inheritance to prevent code duplication. If their functionality is almost identical, use parameters in the urlpattern.

I think you need to study the URL dispatcher a little more: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/